# Print different values using only SELECT in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, select, boolean

Let's say I have a SQLite database with a "Food" table and it's got 3 columns.

Name | Food Group | Healthy

Now let's say Healthy is a boolean, which in SQLite is represented by an INTEGER, meaning that this database returns a 1 for healthy foods and a 0 for unhealthy foods.

Now let's say I wanted to write a query that would return all three rows, but instead of a 1 or 0 for healthy, I wanted it to return "Eat me" for healthy foods, and "Avoid me" for unhealthy foods. How could I write a query that would return this using only a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) here like:

```
select Name, case Healthy when 1 then "Eat me" else "Avoid me" end from Food;
```